# Linq: how to use system.linq.dynamic select expression?

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to build dynamic query with system.linq.dynamic
How I can change the following code to system.linq.dynamic?

```
var qResult = 
    (from m in lstKPProductSales
    group m by new
    {
        m.ItemNo,
        m.ItemName,
    } 
    into d
    select new
    {
        d.Key.ItemNo,
        d.Key.ItemName,
        SumStore2001 = d.Where(c => c.StoreNo == "2001").Sum(c => c.ActualCostAmount),
        SumStore2002 = d.Where(c => c.StoreNo == "2002").Sum(c => c.ActualCostAmount),
        SumStore2003 = d.Where(c => c.StoreNo == "2003").Sum(c => c.ActualCostAmount),
        SumStore2004 = d.Where(c => c.StoreNo == "2004").Sum(c => c.ActualCostAmount),
        SumStore2005 = d.Where(c => c.StoreNo == "2005").Sum(c => c.ActualCostAmount),
        ///...
    }).ToList();
```

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to do the filters using dynamic expressions?

Comment: I wan't to build dynamic query to get value like above query.